# AngularJS + Jquery Gantt - multiple charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a web application using **angularJs** and I need to display gantt charts. I use the **jquery-gantt plugin** and everything works just fine when only one chart is displayed but if I want to display two or more, they seem to have the same source even if it is not the case.

```
<chronogramme source="$ctrl.firstSource"></chronogramme>
<chronogramme source="$ctrl.secondSource"></chronogramme>
```

($ctrl is my alias for my controller, defined with "controllerAs")

For instance, when I update "secondSource", the first chart is updated too and shows the same things as the second one.

Is it even possible to have multiple charts ?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE :**
The problem must be in here, as the selector for the jquery gantt affects every single chart, I will look into it (put this here if it can helps others)
"chronogramme" directive :

```
app.directive("chronogramme", function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
            scope: {
                source: '=source',
                minScale: '=?minScale',
                scale: '=?scale',
                onItemClick: '=onItemClick',
                onTitleClick: '=onTitleClick'
            },
    template: '<div class="gantt"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                if (!scope.minScale) { scope.minScale = 'months'; }
                if (!scope.scale) { scope.scale = 'months'; }
                scope.$watch('source', function(){
                    $(".gantt").gantt({
                        source: scope.source,
                        navigate: "scroll",
                        minScale: scope.minScale,
                        scale: scope.scale,
                        itemsPerPage: 20,
                        waitText: "Chargement...",
                        months: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
                        dow: ["Di", "Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa"],
                        scrollToToday: true,
                        onItemClick: function(data) {
                            scope.onItemClick(data);
                        },
                        onTitleClick: function(data) {
                            scope.onTitleClick(data);
                        }
                    });
      });
    }
};
```

});

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Mixing AngularJS and jQuery can be problematic. Consider using [Angular Gantt](https://www.angular-gantt.com/).

Comment: @georgeawg I did thought about making a reproducible example but I believe it is not a technical problem linked to my code but a more conceptual issue.
However, if it can help, I will try to make one
Thanks for the tip, I will see if angular gantt can solve the issue

Comment: At the very least you could provide the link to the plugin, the code for the `chronogramme` directive. and the code in the controller that causes the error.

Comment: Oh, I feel so bad, didn't even check the directive code...(thought it was embedded in some libraries - tbh I am picking up this project on the fly, i did not code everything)
Now I do think that the problem comes from the directive code, but do not really know what to change.
Thanks a lot for this, I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive is using a class selector to invoke the plugin:

```
template: '<div class="gantt"></div>',
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            if (!scope.minScale) { scope.minScale = 'months'; }
            if (!scope.scale) { scope.scale = 'months'; }
            scope.$watch('source', function(){
                ̶$̶(̶"̶.̶g̶a̶n̶t̶t̶"̶)̶.̶g̶a̶n̶t̶t̶(̶{̶
                element.gantt({
```

Instead of invoking the plugin on all of the elements with the class `gantt`, invoke it on the element specific to the directive.

Also the directive `replace` property has been deprecated. It could cause problems if the directive is used with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thank a lot ! This works as expected !
I was trying to add the id attrs to the scope to make a more specific selector but it did not work :/

Answer (score 0):

Using [Angular Gantt](https://www.angular-gantt.com/) clearly solves the issue. You can check the code for `gantt` directive inside the library it's much complex and you don't need to invest time on creating one in your application using just jquery version of the library. So with using the gantt directive you can have multiple charts on same view. (As of course it's created with isolated scope). Here's example of two charts on same view with different data set: https://plnkr.co/edit/lyBH7ZnZ5PgThqe46YKk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the whole project uses a jquery a lot so I try to use it as much as possible. Moreover, changing all the charts would be irrelevant now that I see the "chronogramme" directive is badly written.
But thanks anyway !